# Selected checkbox values in bootstrap modal change checkbox value in parent window

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

check box in modal selects the check box values in the parent window

When a bootstrap modal has a form with check box values, if the values are selected in the modal I need the same checkbox form values to be selected on the parent window

the idea solution would be for the user to make selections in the modal, say selecting 2-3-4 items and on closing the modal the parent window is updated with the selected checkboxs, any help with this would be grateful thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>

  <form>
    <h3>Select your favorite sports:</h3>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="football" name="sport"> Football</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="baseball" name="sport"> Baseball</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="cricket" name="sport"> Cricket</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="boxing" name="sport"> Boxing</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="racing" name="sport"> Racing</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="swimming" name="sport"> Swimming</label>
    <br><br>
 </form>

  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form>
       <h3>Select your favorite sports:</h3>
       <label><input type="checkbox" value="football" name="sport"> Football</label>
       <label><input type="checkbox" value="baseball" name="sport"> Baseball</label>
       <label><input type="checkbox" value="cricket" name="sport"> Cricket</label>
       <label><input type="checkbox" value="boxing" name="sport"> Boxing</label>
       <label><input type="checkbox" value="racing" name="sport"> Racing</label>
       <label><input type="checkbox" value="swimming" name="sport"> Swimming</label>
       <br>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include you current script you are using to implement your requirements in a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate your current issue you are getting. In general if you need multiple UI components to reflect the same data you would use a shared data store, reaching from a simple variable to cookies, objects stored in data attributes or local storage, etc.. There is many ways of doing it but you need to try to implement one and only if you have issues with the one you picked post the code here.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g9e2s8vj/9/)...

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.modal_check_box').change(function(){
    var test = $(this).val();
    $('input[value^='+test+']').prop('checked',true);
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>

  <form>
    <h3>Select your favorite sports:</h3>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="football" name="sport"> Football</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="baseball" name="sport"> Baseball</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="cricket" name="sport"> Cricket</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="boxing" name="sport"> Boxing</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="racing" name="sport"> Racing</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="swimming" name="sport"> Swimming</label>
    <br><br>
 </form>

  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

  <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form>
       <h3>Select your favorite sports:</h3>
       <label><input type="checkbox" class="modal_check_box" value="football" name="sport"> Football</label>
       <label><input type="checkbox" class="modal_check_box" value="baseball" name="sport"> Baseball</label>
       <label><input type="checkbox" class="modal_check_box" value="cricket" name="sport"> Cricket</label>
       <label><input type="checkbox" class="modal_check_box" value="boxing" name="sport"> Boxing</label>
       <label><input type="checkbox" class="modal_check_box" value="racing" name="sport"> Racing</label>
       <label><input type="checkbox" class="modal_check_box" value="swimming" name="sport"> Swimming</label>
       <br>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have added class `modal_check_box` for only modal check boxes (need to find which one is used in modal).